# what does isomorphism mean in the context of software engineering?

Tags: types, computer-science, conceptual

I keep hearing the term 'isomorphic', particularly in relation to polymorphism, but I don't understand what it means.

What is an isomorphic type?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism and https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/isomorphic